# When using S3 in AWS, how do you manage access to specific images?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ami, amazon-cognito

I am developing image server through S3 in AWS(Amazon Web Service) but i should solve the management issue
What i mean is that end user should be able to specific images in S3
For that, i am thinking about IAM(Identity access management) for allowing some users to access specific images.

What i want to know is that whether there is other solutions or not.
Actually, i have found about cognito but unfortunately cognito is supported in only 2 regions....

If you have a good idea, please give me explanation  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing in the suite of AWS services that fits your use case 100%.

While [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) is only available in 2 regions, this does not restrict you to accessing S3 from only those 2 regions with credentials vended from the service. You could Amazon Cognito and IAM roles to define a policy that would allow for limited permissions to a set of files based on the prefix. However, at the current time, role policies would allow you to restrict access to 2 classes of files:

- "Public files" - files accessible via *all* identities in your pool.
- "Private files" - files accessible only to a specific identity in your pool.

If you wanted to support restricting access to specific files to specific users in your application you would need to handle this through a backend application that would proxy the access to the files in S3.